# tns preview not working on android with nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I created a super simple app that has 3 tabs and a list generated with an http call/axios.

When I run `tns run android --bundle` everything works fine but when I try `tns preview` using the playground app on my android phone I get this error:

```
Cannot compile /data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/main.js

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/main.js, line: 1, column: 67

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266


    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1028)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5658)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)

Executing after-watch hook from /home/badr/projects/ns/annuaire/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
Executing after-watch hook from /home/badr/projects/ns/annuaire/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
Executing after-watch hook from /home/badr/projects/ns/annuaire/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `--bundle` flag for the `tns preview` command. It should work with `tns preview --bundle`.

The `--bundle` flag is responsible for running webpack, which compiles the `.vue` files.